# Map to List of Maps

Tags: groovy

My original list looks like

```
def l = [a:apple, a:application, b:batch, c:commandLine, c:crash]
```

I need to convert it to

```
[ ["a":"apple"],["a":"application"],["b":"batch"],["c":"commandLine"],["c":"crash"] ]
```

How do I convert it?

Comment: Your assignment statement is invalid in Groovy.  It has to be def l=[a:"apple", a:"application",...].  Unless enclosed within quotes, it will not compile.  And if you define something like [a:"1", b:"2"], it's already a Map.  Lists are defined like [a,b,c,d]

Comment: Is `l` a map like: `l = [a:'apple', b:'batch']` or a list like `l = ['a:apple', 'b:batch']`

Comment: I doubt if this is the intent, but if all of { a, b, c, application, batch, commandLine, crash} are objects, then the assignment is legal Groovy. That said, the question is indeed suspect.

Comment: Yes I need def l= [["a":"apple"], ["a":"application"]]

Answer (score 1):

You input list isn't invalid Groovy, so there are (at least) two possible assumptions:

**If your input is a Map** such as:

```
def l = [a: 'apple', b: 'batch']
```

you can do:

```
l.collect { k,v -> [(k): v] }
```

**If your input is a list of map-like strings** such as:

```
def l = ['a:apple', 'b:batch']
```

you need something like:

```
l.collect {
    def tokens = it.split(/:/)
    [(tokens[0]): tokens[1]]
}
```

**UPDATE**
or a simpler approach like:

```
l.collect { it.split(/:/).toSpreadMap() }
```

ending up with a [SpreadMap](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/SpreadMap.html)

Comment: mustnt it be ["$k":"$v"] ?

Comment: No. 'v' is always a value, but you must escape the key.

Comment: Although wrapping the key in parens is better since it preserves the type of the key. I only used the string since he wanted string keys specifically. A generic map to array of maps would use `[(k):v]`.

Comment: I don't think `l` in the question is a map. Key `a` is repeated.

Comment: `l` isn't even valid Groovy. If he meant `l = ['a:val', 'b:val']` that would definitely change the problem.

Comment: Yes exactly. `l.collect { [it.split(/:/)] }` is what I can try from my phone, if that is the case as you said. :)

Comment: That would give a list of lists: `[ ['a', 'val'], ['b', 'val'] ]`. You'd have to do something like: `l.collect { def toks = it.split(/:/); [(toks[0]):toks[1]] }`

Comment: Yes, correct. I was overusing as [k, v]. I think there can be a simpler way.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect both possibilities.

Comment: @codelark gives me message "No signature of method:split applicable for String values[:]  Possible solutions: split(groovy.lang.Closure)

Comment: Can you post a gist? The code above works in the groovy console.